# Byte Variable For Loop

Tags: arduino, byte, arduino-ide

Please help me interpret this for-loop:

```
for (byte color_bit = 23 ; color_bit != 255 ; color_bit--) {
    ...do something
}
```

I think I understand (from Googling & StackOverflow) that 'color_bit' here is an UNSIGNED variable. So this means that the loop will count down from 23 to 0. But then what happens next? Does it attempt to start at 255 and continue to count down?  But because the test is "!= 255" it will stop?

In my mind this seems to be the logic, but the tool I'm using (Arduino IDE) doesn't have a debugger, so I can't step through the code to see the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will see bit_color = 23..0 (24 iterations) provided 'byte' is 8 bit unsigned. Your loop stops when color_bit=255. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a serial print line as shown below:

```
 for (byte color_bit = 23 ; color_bit != 255 ; color_bit--) {
      Serial.print(bit_color, DEC);
 }
```

To test/debug the counting sequence.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Since it's code that ends up on the Arduino chip, there is no console.  BUT, following your advice, I set up the code in the Visual Studio C# compiler and stepped through it.

What I found is that after the loop steps down to zero, the very next iteration of color_bit = 255 (and the loop ends).

Comment: Since you are using the Arduino IDE you should be able to use the build-in serial monitor to look at the output created by the Serial.print command. It uses the same serial port and cable as used for programming the code on to the board. Look at the example under Communication->ASCII table.

Comment: Sure enough! Thanks for that tip!!